# npm install global not working on mac, Says I don't have permissions? Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules

Tags: npm, terminal, permissions, installation, parcel

I don't have permissions to my node modules files, It is not allowing me to install or update anything globally.

I know that using -sudo is not recommended for it can cause problems with permissions later. I thought I could update npm and node to solve the issue but I don't have permissions to do that.

```
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ended up using this code and it's working now.

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```